# setting up initial state in jquery?

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I have a form which has follow-up questions that should be shown only shown if they answer a particular other question a certain way. The way I have it set up right now works great if I start out with a blank form. However, when the user comes back to edit the form and its loading whether the checkboxes are pre-checked from the database (via php), my design is breaking down.

So I need some advice or suggestions on how to best restructure my jquery code so that it will show and hide the correct elements when the form loads.

Right now, I have a number of .change() functions for checkboxes or option buttons that cause other (or multiple) elements to hide and/or show, such as the following:

```
$("#elt_prev_divorced").change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
                $("#questions_divorced").show("slow"); 
        } else { 
                $("#questions_divorced").hide("slow"); 
        }
});

$("input").change(function () {
    var selected_item = $(this).attr('id');

switch (selected_item) {
        case "elt_married":
            $("#elt_inrel_yes").attr('checked', true);
            $("#elt_reldes_married").attr('checked', true); 
            $("#li_spouse_or_partner").show("slow");
            $("#li_marriages").show("slow");
            break;
        case ...
}
```

And then I have a CSS class called "initially_hidden" that is set for all items that shouldn't be shown when the form loads if the form is blank. In my document ready function, I hide everything with that CSS tag.

```
(function($) {
    $(".initially_hidden").hide(); 
})(jQuery);
```

After I hide those elements, however, I now need to do the equivalent of all of those .change() functions to handle the form being loaded with existing data. I know I could copy and paste my change functions into document ready to do this, but aside from being certainly horrific style were I do that, I would much prefer to minimize duplicate code. So how could I do this best/efficiently? I am somewhat new to JQuery, so I'm not sure what direction to take here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly in your css `.initially_hidden` can have `display:none` set in the stylesheet or the in-page style. jQuery will set `display:block` or whatever in the inline style. So I don't see the sense of calling `hide()` on your elements with the class `initially_hidden`.

What I would do is handle this on the server side and set `initially_hidden` on all elements that should *not* be displayed and let my css hide those elements.

This way, all the elements are on the form that should be displayed and all that should not be displayed are hidden. If you have a checkbox checking which will make other elements visible, I would suggest you do 1 of 2 things.

- Traverse the dom relative to your checkbox to determine which element should be displayed, hence no need to hardcode an id. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDyn3/79/) has an example of something like this.
- Add a custom attribute to your checkbox which contains the id for the div/element you want to display:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" eleToShow="marriedQuestion" class="questionCheckbox" />
<input type="checkbox" eleToShow="divorcedQuestion" class="questionCheckbox" />
<input type="checkbox" eleToShow="poligamyQuestion" class="questionCheckbox" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".questionCheckbox").change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
                $("#"+$(this).attr("eleToShow")).show("slow"); 
        } else { 
                $("#"+$(this).attr("eleToShow")).hide("slow"); 
        }
});
```

Hope this helps and makes sense.

Comment: Handling the hiding/showing of elements on the server side for initial load would require complete duplication of the logic for which questions are hidden/shown in both php and javascript, and since I need to handle on-click events as well, that would seem to give no advantages to reducing duplicated code. 

Also, some checkboxes (or option button selections) will cause multiple elements to become shown and other multiple elements to become hidden. will this solution break down for needing to update a list of elements?

Comment: I did [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kqreJ/13/) just now for someone else, but would something like this help? Clicking on a link the first time adds a div, clicking on it a second time highlights it. I offer this just for the basic concept, I realize your problem is different, but the divs that are highlighted in this case are dynamically generated so the highlighting is dynamic.

Comment: If I'm reading you right, you are suggesting generating code to dynamically call the .change functions?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting 1 `change` function that handles all the question and answer divs. All you have to do is create a checkbox with a custom attribute `eleToShow` which contains the name of the div you want to show or hide when the checkbox is (un)checked. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHcfj/5/) I provide 2 option, one to use if you are **not** using ajax to populate content, the other to use if you are.

Answer (score 2):

In your document-ready function, call `$("#elt_prev_divorced").change()` to execute the handler you've already registered.

Comment: That definitely looks feasible. Not quite as clean as I would hope, but much better than copying the code from the change functions. Do you know if there's a way to call *all* of the change handlers at once? There's about 20 of them, and I'm afraid I might miss one on accident.